# how can i integrate Spring Boot WebSocket with Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, websocket, apache-kafka

I want to integrate kafka with Spring Boot WebSocket project, the official documentation of  it uses STOMP protocol by default which don't support kafka like a brocker messages. So my question is, how can I integrate kafka with Spring Boot WebSocket ? and thank you so much.